# Switching User Agent in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, user-agent

So what I wanted to do was change the user agent from desktop to iphone. I successfully did that and it works. However, I had a question about why Firefox is launching two windows. I also wanted to the community for some help and input on what I'm doing wrong!

```
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.get(config.host_url +'/sai')
    self.assertTrue(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.page-wrap > div.vertical-name-wrapper.underlined'))
    driver.quit()
```

This code here actually opens a firefox browser twice (Is it supposed to?) I would like to open just one browser window with the user agent already changed.

Comment: Which selenium package version are you using?

Comment: I can't duplicate this. Running this code without the assert and using Google's home page as the URL brings up only one Firefox window on my system (MacOS 10.8 with a stock selenium installation with pip on Python 2.7).